# How to make GNU screen create new window on same path under running process (ex: top)

Tags: gnu-screen

I added my .screenrc below line to create new window on same path.

```
bind , stuff "screen^M" #send command 'screen' to current screen session
```

It creates new window on current path well. However if it some process is running (ex. top), the new screen command cannot pass to current session, so it fails.

Is there any way to avoid this situation. When I compile a source, It takes long times so I can not make new window (with same path) by this method.

Comment: this issue was touched by here https://superuser.com/a/989330/371256

Answer (score 0):

I add self answer.
I get idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418619/1265770.

1. edit PROMPT_COMMAND variable in .bashrc

   export PROMPT_COMMAND="screen -X chdir "$PWD"; PROMPT_COMMAND" //evaluate PWD whenever cd command
2. edit your .screenrc

   bind , 'screen' //map , to create new window from $PWD